# Does notify happen-before wakeup of wait?

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable, happens-before

Is this program

```
std::condition_variable cond_var;
std::mutex mtx;
std::atomic<int> value {0};

const auto mem_ord = std::memory_order_seq_cst;

std::thread notify_thread([&]
    {
        {
            //std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock (mtx);
            value.store (1, mem_ord);
        }
        cond_var.notify ();
    });

{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock (mtx);
    cond_var.wait (lock, [&] { return value.load (mem_ord) != 0; });
}

notify_thread.join ();
```

guaranteed to terminate or may it deadlock? What if one would use `mem_ord = std::memory_order_relaxed`? May there be any other reasons to hold a lock while `store`-ing into the `atomic<int>`? [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) demands that one has to uncomment the line with the lock-guard in the `notify_thread`.

I would expect that (with any memory order) the `store` *happens-before* the notify, which *happens-before* the (potential) wakeup in the `wait`, which *happens-before* the `load`. (I say "potential wakeup" because the `notify-thread` may, of course, finish before the `wait` on the condition-variable in which case there never will be a wakeup). So, I would assume that (with any memory order) there is no need to uncomment the line with the lock-guard.

Comment: the happens-before guarantee is in `30.5[thread.condition]p4` but breaking the condition variable protocol seems very suspect

Comment: Imagine the main thread checks `value.load != 0` , then `cond_var.notify()` happens, then the main thread goes back to sleep (waiting for `cond_var`). Then the main thread will miss the notify.

Comment: @dyp Yeah! That's it. Thus, the lock is necessary. Thanks very much.